# Combine Vlookups

Tags: excel, vlookup, nested

I'm trying to combine two vlookup statements.  Here is what I have:

=VLOOKUP(C2,'Purchase Order Browse'!$Q$4:$R$65,2)

What I want it to do if it doesn't find anything above is to then do a vlookup on this data set

=VLOOKUP(C2,'Work Order Browse'!M4:N123,2)

How do I combine the two to work together?

Comment: I assume you have deliberately omitted the 4th argument of VLOOKUP? If you do that then the **lookup range** (in first formula that would be Q4:Q65) must be sorted ascending (and you may get a "closest match" if there's no exact match). If you only want exact matches you should use FALSE as 4th argument in your VLOOKUP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a VLOOKUP does not find a match, it should return `#N/A`, so you could add it into an `IF` statement.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C2,'Purchase Order Browse'!$Q$4:$R$65,2)), VLOOKUP(C2,'Work Order Browse'!M4:N123,2), VLOOKUP(C2,'Purchase Order Browse'!$Q$4:$R$65,2))
```

#### Update for Excel 2007+

As pointed out by barry houdini, Excel 2007 and later supports an `IFERROR` function that takes two params `IFERROR(value, value_if_error)`:

> IFERROR function returns a value you specify if a formula evaluates to an error; otherwise, returns the result of the formula.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,'Purchase Order Browse'!$Q$4:$R$65,2), VLOOKUP(C2,'Work Order Browse'!M4:N123,2))
```

Comment: This worked.  Thanks.  You guys/gals are awesome!  This site is awesome!

Comment: If you are using Excel 2007 or later you could also use IFERROR function, that would avoid repeating any of the VLOOKUPs - the syntax is =IFERROR(Vlookup1,Vlookup2)